# Invalid MySQL axis-order on official doc site

Tags: mysql, sql, spatial

During learning SPATIAL data in MySQL v.8.0  find error in docs on [page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-geojson-functions.html) .
This query:

```
SET @json = '{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.0]}';
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(@json));
```

should return WKT with this axis-order:

```
POINT(102 0)
```

but, it return this order:

```
POINT(0 102)
```

Maybe I make some mistake, waiting for your help.

Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b5a9de67da72e55cc43c6752920616f4 .

Comment: Spatial coordinates are encoded in the order `(latitude, longitude)` in WKT (I find indirect reference only in User Manual - but I have searched negligently) but in backward order in GeoJSON (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-3.1.1).

Answer (score 1):

The display problem is related to **srid** optional parameter of `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON()` which has value a ***default*** value of **4326** (stands for **EPSG:4326** Coordinate system **"WGS84, unprojected"**). It displays in **latitude**, **longitude** order.

Mostly, the data is stored in **EPSG:4326** and displayed in **EPSG:3857** (**Pseudo-Mercator**, **Spherical Mercator** or **Web Mercator**) in which the components ( **latitude**, **longitude** ) are ordered reversely.

So, you need to use such a way

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(@JSON,1,3857));
```

in order to display in **longitude**, **latitude** order.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eae91f3ff448ca923e4e22fd390bb29c)</kbd>

Comment: Ok, but what problem in mysql docs example, and why I cannot replicate result?

Comment: @TarasPinchuk it should be a mistake the order at the bottom of that page (`POINT(102 0)`).